# Mongodb updated but not showing in redirected page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using Node/Express as a web framework, here is how I structured the delete action (it's nested in a higher level route):

```
.delete((req, res) => {
  db.collection('collection-name').findOneAndDelete({ topic_title: req.body.topic_title}, 
  (err, item) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('item deleted');
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Client-Side request:

```
$('.delete-button').click(function(){
$('.topic-title').text($('.topic-title').text());
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + $('.topic-title').text() + '?')){
  fetch('topics', {
    method: 'delete',
    headers: { "Content-Type" : 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'topic_title' : $('.topic-title').text()
    })
  });
}
```

When I hit the delete button, the page redirect to an index of all the entries in the db.

The problem is that the deleted entry still displays in the redirected page, until the page is refreshed. I'm also having this problem with the update action.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How does the ```delete``` action get called from the view?  In other words, what does the button do to call this action?

Comment: I'm using a fetch command on the client-side to send the title of the entry.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? I'm afraid i'm unsure what the 'fetch command' is.

Comment: `fetch('topics', {
        method: 'delete',
        headers: { "Content-Type" : 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'topic_title' : $('.topic-title').text()
        })` Here's the reference I used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same problem I was having myself although I was using a jQuery $.ajax call in a similar way that you are using the fetch APU.

If you think about what's happening, you are sending a request, separate to the rest of your page, off to the server to trigger the `delete` action within Express.  This in turn is deleting the record from the database.  Fine, no problems there.

The problem occurs when the `delete` action finishes.  You are redirecting this to the `/` route but it is the delete request which is being redirected not an actual request for a page.

I couldn't figure out what was happening intially when I encountered this (earlier today actually).  My solution was to, once I knew the database had been updated, remove the element from the page thereby eliminating the need for a page refresh / redirect.  My code I have now looks like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.button').on('click', function(e){
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/',
      method: "DELETE",
      data: {item: id}
    })
    .done(function(data){
      $('#' + id).parent().remove();
    });
  });
});
```

There is probably a more elegant way to handle the removal of the (in my case) list item but I haven't got round to looking at that yet.

Also, it might be worth reconsidering the fetch API if this is something more than a personal project as browser support seems to be [very limited](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch).

Comment: Yup that helped! Thanks! I did it by changing the redirect that was by the server to a redirect by the client and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mongoose instead MongoClient.
It works perfect on my project with similar functions
http://mongoosejs.com/